# List sheet names in a sheet, hyperlink them, and update list whenever sheets are added/deleted

Tags: vba, excel

I have found several codes that lists all the sheet names in a sheet and hyperlink them.
I want to list all the sheets in the sheet "ListSheet" and make them hyperlinks.

Two issues with the following code:

1) It should delete the previous list and insert the new one, in case I add or delete sheets (sub add_list() or sub delete_list()), but when I delete sheets the list keeps the old sheet names (so the list is probably not deleted before the new is created).

2) The list always created in the same cell and down, but not always created in the sheet "ListSheet". Is that because the "active" sheet is changed in the "sub add_list()" and "sub delete_list()"?

```
Sub add_list()
Sheets(4).Copy Before:=Sheets("8")
Call TOC
End Sub
```

And

```
Sub delete_sheet()
ActiveSheet.Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Call TOC
End Sub
```

And

```
Sub TOC()
Dim objSheet As Object
Dim intRow   As Integer
Dim strCol   As Integer
Dim GCell As Range

SearchText = "Word"
Set GCell = Worksheets("ListSheet").Cells.Find(SearchText).Offset(2, -1)

GCell.End(xlDown).ClearContents

Set objSheet = Excel.Sheets
intRow = GCell.Row
strCol = GCell.Column

For Each objSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    With Worksheet
    Cells(intRow, strCol).Select
    Worksheets("ListSheet").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "'" & objSheet.Name & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=objSheet.Name
        With Selection.Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .FontStyle = "Normal"
            .Size = 11
            .Strikethrough = False
            .Superscript = False
            .Subscript = False
            .OutlineFont = False
            .Shadow = False
            .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
        End With
    intRow = intRow + 1
    End With
Next
```

Any input, hints or lectures are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: how does this even work: `With Worksheet` will fail at run-time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few main principles of (VBA) programming not incorporated your original code that are probably causing it fail:

1. Avoid `Select` and `ActiveSheet` (except when absolutely needed).
2. Declare all variables with explicit types and names (using Option Explicit to ensure variables are used properly).
3. Break procedures into smaller components (not a huge issue with your code, just as a bonus :))

This refactored code should work a lot better:

```
Option Explicit

Sub addList()

    Sheets(4).Copy Before:=Sheets("8")
    writeTOC

End Sub

Sub deleteSheet()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveSheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    writeTOC

End Sub

Sub writeTOC()

    Dim listSheet As Worksheet
    Set listSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ListSheet")

    Dim searchText As String
    searchText = "Word"

    Dim gCell As Range
    Set gCell = listSheet.Cells.Find(searchText).Offset(2, -1)
    gCell.End(xlDown).ClearContents

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        listSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=gCell.Offset(i), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & sht.Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=sht.Name
        formatLinkCell gCell.Offset(i)

        i = i + 1

    Next

End Sub

Sub formatLinkCell(rng As Range)

    With rng.font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Normal"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually figured it out, but your code looks much better!

Comment: Did you mean with ring.font

Comment: @Scott Holtzman

Now the list is in place. If possible, could you help me with 2 more challenges:

Comment: @Scott Holtzman

1) I have a code that changes the sheet name depending on several cell names. Instead of changing when the cell input changes, can this be done automatically?

2) Could it be a part of the "Sub add_sheet" code? Like, if I add a sheet, it should be named depending on the cells, and since it is copied and the cells are the same, the name will obviously be taken, in which case the name should be "N02" instead of "N01" (instead of the default "(2)").Thansk in advance!

Comment: @DFH - please post a new question if you cannot figure it out and where you are stuck in your efforts to make it work.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman: I asked the questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48184152/9102830
Thanks for all your help!